# What disrupts the inherit logic order of autoincrement that leads to illogical ordering of ids in the absence of an ORDER clause?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

On occasion I come across a database table on a project where when no sorting is applied (`ORDER` clause) that the ids are *not* in their inherit logical order.

```
1
178
3
144
2
```

Under the presumption that no one went out of their way and started manually changing the `id` column values for any reason and that the `id` column is set to `autoincrement` what would lead to this scenario and should whatever that cause/those causes should be an issue to be addressed for security or data integrity purposes?

Comment: Without an `order by` the database is free to return the rows in any order it likes. There is no such thing as an "inherent logical order" of a table.

Comment: Relying on the order of a resultset *without* an explicit `order by` clause is a recipe for disaster.  You need to have an explicit `order by` in the query if that's what you (or your app) is expecting.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just elaborate on @a_horse_with_no_name 's comment. A table (relation) is a set of rows (tuples). By definition, a set is unordered. Asking what the next row is without specifying what you mean by next (ORDER BY), is like asking what colour joy has (well when it comes to power tools everyone knows that it is green and black ;-).

Assume that no rows reside in memory and that another connection reads id=186 into memory. Now your query asks for:

```
select id from T limit 1;
```

What would you consider the most sensible thing for the DBMS to do, return 186 from memory, or read a bunch of rows from disk to return the lowest id?

What's the benefit of treat a table as unordered one might ask? The optimizer tries to execute the query as efficient as possible. It can re-arrange the query in a number of ways, as long as it does not violate the semantics of the query. If it would have to take the ordering into consideration, it would severely cripple the freedom to choose the most efficient plan for the query.

Comment: Whenever you `INSERT` with `autoincrement` a new `id` is generated in a +1 fashion so the data is "naturally" `ORDER BY id` how it is stored. When this issue occurs it only happens in certain scenarios and with certain tables so there is certainly something causing the issue. I appreciate you trying to help though this isn't the answer for this scenario.

Comment: No matter what you think, the RDBMS will hand over the rows in what way it finds most efficient. Even if you get the rows 999 times in the order you expect, there is no guarantee that it will do so the 1000:th time, and you should never ever assume that it will unless it is clearly documented somewhere. If you can find such guarantee for *any* RDBMS, please share.

Comment: *Whenever you INSERT with autoincrement a new id is generated in a +1 fashion* That's not right. The only guarantees are: 1) the generated number is above previously generated one (and so it is above the current maximal one stored in a table already) 2) any generated value will never be generated in future (until generator reset), even it will cause an overflow and insertion hang. `+1` incremental step is the simplest one, of course, but it is not guaranteed. Moreover, some DBMS allows to set the incremental step to the value other then `+1`.

Answer (score 2):

- `DELETE` might leave a 'hole' in the data; a subsequent `INSERT` may fill in that hole with the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` id.
- `UPDATE` can change the length of a record, thereby perhaps necessitating putting it somewhere else.
- `REPLACE` deletes a row(s) and inserts a row, thereby creating a new `id`.
- `GROUP BY` (or other constructs) may pick a different ordering.
- A `JOIN` may pick either table to 'start' with.
- A `ROLLBACK'd` transaction may lose ids.
- MyISAM, especially after a bunch of deletes/updates/inserts, is very likely to provide rows in an unpredictable order.  (InnoDB stores the data in `PRIMARY KEY` order, so it is usually predictable.)
- etc, etc.

If you want specifics, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the full `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Rick, your replies are always welcomed though unfortunately I'm about one week from finishing the audit of my platform and going out in to the 'wild'. I'm having trouble getting older copies of MariaDB to run (I literally just stop the service and copy the entire directory) so I can't post as I act fairly quickly and exported, cleaned up the `ORDER` so-to-speak, emptied and imported the data back in to the table (no many rows any way). It's definitely an anomaly because I don't do anything different with that table than the others. Thank you Rick.

Comment: @John - Oh, another thing -- MyISAM is more prone to what you saw than InnoDB.